# Very high Xorg memory usage with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xorg, ram, memory-leak

I'm having a memory leak issue with Xorg and it's taking up huge portions on my memory. Right now, it's up to 41.2% of memory and I haven't even been using the computer that much.

This is some output regarding it.

```
    Linux grant-N501VW 4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root      1402  0.0  0.6 400860 99080 tty1     Sl+  Jul29   0:03 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/120/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
root      2097  0.0 34.4 6136080 5608064 tty2  Sl+  Jul29   4:26 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
grant    23603  0.0  0.0  21536  1096 pts/0    S+   23:11   0:00 grep --color=auto xorg

          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15903        7914        5325         352        2663        7450
Swap:           716           0         716
```

All drivers are updated as well. Restarting will reset the memory usage but it still creeps up over time.

Comment: **did you try to set memory limits**

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your memory use

Comment: @Panther Xorg memory usage increases over time. It's gotten to 9GB of just Xorg when I wasn't even doing anything. Since I have 16GB of RAM it hasn't slowed me down too much but I want to pin point the issue.

Comment: Unused ram is wasted ram. Is it causing some sort of problem?

Comment: @Panther how would you justify 9GB of RAM used by Xorg? Of course, using RAM for caching etc. when it is not used by applications is reasonable. But applications shouldn't occupy more RAM than they need; and Xorg occupying 9GB sounds like a memory leak, especially because it happens over time.

Comment: I do not have enough information and I do not see xorg using 9 GB of ram, can you please clarify

Comment: Read my above comment.

Comment: @Panther, for me I have not noticed RAM used by Xorg to be freed when I add info to RAM, I often experience freezes and wait for OOM killer (or firefox tabs crash).

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

I managed to figure out that the issue was a custom wallpaper systemd service that I was running to update the wallpaper every 30 seconds using [pscirlce](https://gitlab.com/mildlyparallel/pscircle). Apparently I misconfigured the service and it wasn't removing something from memory properly. I don't know the exact cause of the issue, but removing this fixed my issue.

Unfortunately I lost the .service files so I don't have any more information for further research.